# Convert lat/lon to data in Georgia state plane

Tags: python, gis, map-projections, proj

I am trying to convert some data in x,y,z (ECEF) to Georgia state plane. First I convert x,y,z to lat,lon,alt and then try to convert it into Georgia state plane. When I look at the data, the numbers don't seem right (looking at converted data that I have from others).

```
from pyproj import Proj, transform, CRS, Transformer
import pyproj as pyproj


x = 685204; y = -4557333; z = 2766371;
ecef = pyproj.Proj(proj='geocent', ellps='WGS84', datum='WGS84')
lla  = pyproj.Proj(proj='latlong', ellps='WGS84', datum='WGS84')
lon, lat, alt = pyproj.transform(ecef, lla, x, y, z, radians=False)

inProj  = CRS.from_epsg(4326)
outProj = CRS.from_epsg(2239)

proj  = Transformer.from_crs(inProj, outProj)
x2,y2 = proj.transform(lon,lat,radians=False)
```

Comment: Can you give examples of what you expect from this?

Comment: This may be a good question for https://gis.stackexchange.com.